# Stack cleanup on IA32 after call/ret

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I just started learning x86 and don't quite understand how the stack is cleaned up after a call/ret on IA32. I compiled the following code with `gcc -m32 -no-pie`:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char text[108];
    int x = read(0, text, 108);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, the compiler makes space for 120 (116 + 4 bytes) on the stack. The first two words `ebp-4` and `ebp-8` remain unused (for memory alignment maybe?), and `ebp-12` is reserved for storing `x`. `ebp-16` to `ebp-120` is reserved for the input text. Before calling `read` three values (4 bytes each) are pushed onto the stack, which are (after RET) later cleaned up with `add esp, 16`. But shouldn't it be `add esp, 12` since we only pushed 3 values? Is it not overwriting the first/last character of "text"? I already drew the stack multiple times on paper, but I still don't see my mistake.

```
lea     ecx, [esp+4]
and     esp, -16
push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
sub     esp, 116
sub     esp, 4
push    108
lea     eax, [ebp-120]
push    eax
push    0
call    read
add     esp, 16
mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], eax
mov     eax, 0
mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
leave
lea     esp, [ecx-4]
ret
```

**Edit:** Shouldn't also at the very end the stack and base pointers be restored, i.e., `mov esp, ebp ; pop ebp` so that the very last `ret` can access the stored instruction pointer and jump out of the main function?

Comment: re: edit: that's exactly what `leave` does; check the ISA manual.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/leave

Comment: There's a `sub     esp, 4` that's aligning the stack args before the 3 pushes; `add esp,16` is popping that space too.  Note that this is un-optimized code so it's over-complicated; with optimization the compiler would (hopefully) have done that `sub` as part of the one reserving space for the array.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that command!

Comment: Now I see it ... I did not pay attention to the `push    ecx`. Now it also makes sense with `sub     esp, 4` and increasing it by 16 again. Thanks a lot @PeterCordes!